# CSS Mega Menus: How to target ul's except those in divs

Tags: css

With CSS Mega Menus, there are many possibilities. But it also mean that I need to handle things like I want to style children `<ul>` as nav only if they are not in a div.

I created a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/av5zr/ demonstrating the problem

The list in the 2nd menu should be a normal list. How can I style children ul's as lists only if they are not part of a div? 1 way might be to reset list styles with `.megaMenu-hor div ul` but I will need to duplicate "normal" list styles in 2 places, in the menu style and in the site's main style, which I prefer to keep separate

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use it like this:

```
...<li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <div class="normal-list"><!--add a class-->
            <p>This is a div</p>
            <ul>...
```

Then all you need to select it in CSS is this:

```
.megaMenu-hor div.normal-list ul{
    display: none;  
}
```

Hope it works..

Comment: Isn't `display: none` rather misleading here?

Comment: actually display none was to hide drop downs, I could style `ul` as lists only if they have a certain class but that will mean I will have to have class names scattered all over

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't.

Either you need to duplicate your styles to undo the menu `<ul />` style for normal `<ul />`s within a menu **OR**  you need to add a class to the menu `<ul />`s and target them specifically

**EDIT**

Just read other answerer's comment. My understanding is that you want to keep the main `<ul />` styles and menu `<ul />` styles separate. Otherwise an easier suggestion might be to write out your default `<ul />` styles like this:

```
ul,
.megaMenu-hor div ul {
/* whatever */
}
```